# How can i merge the question and choices array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am still new on using Laravel and manipulating the data in arrays.

basically I have two tables that I need to merge in.

First is the questions and second is the choices.

This is my array for the questions

```
[0] => Array (
    [id] => 1
    [question] => What major problem are Texans having?
    )
[1] => Array (
    [id] => 2
    [question] => What did civic leaders suggest?
    )
[2] => Array (
    [id] => 3
    [question] => What is the author’s general intention in writing this article?
    )
```

and this is my array for choices

```
[0] => Array (
    [question_id] => 1
    [choice] => gas shortage
    )
[1] => Array (
    [question_id] => 1
    [choice] => panic buying
    )
[2] => Array (
    [question_id] => 1
    [choice] => Hurricane Harvey
    )
[3] => Array (
    [question_id] => 1
    [choice] => help from oil companies
    )
[4] => Array (
    [question_id] => 2
    [choice] => gas shortage
    )
[5] => Array (
    [question_id] => 2
    [choice] => panic buying
    )
[6] => Array (
    [question_id] => 2
    [choice] => Hurricane Harvey
    )
[7] => Array (
    [question_id] => 2
    [choice] => help from oil companies
    )
[8] => Array (
    [question_id] => 3
    [choice] => gas shortage
    )
[9] => Array (
    [question_id] => 3
    [choice] => panic buying
    )
[10] => Array (
    [question_id] => 3
    [choice] => Hurricane Harvey
    )
[11] => Array (
    [question_id] => 3
    [choice] => help from oil companies
    )
```

I am thinking on how can i combine the two arrays based on the question_id of the choices? so that when i display it on my view it will just be very easy. i have no idea on using the multi dimensional array, and i am asking here for help on how to do it.

here is the code that i have currently on getting the data.

This is for getting the questions

```
    $questions = Question::select(
      'question.id',
      'question.component AS question',
    )
    ->from('questions AS question')
    ->leftJoin('scenarios AS scenario', 'scenario.id', '=', 'question.scenario_id')
    ->where('question.scenario_id',1)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

And this is for getting the choices for the questions

````
    $choices = Question_choice::select(
      'choice.question_id',
      'choice AS choice'
    )
    ->from('question_choices AS choice')
    ->leftJoin('questions AS question', 'question.id', '=', 'choice.question_id')
    ->where('question.id', ```looping the id data that i have in the question table```)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
````

the idea that i am having is like this.

```
[0] => Array (
    [id] => 1
    [question] => What major problem are Texans having?
       =>[choices] =>[0] gas shortage
                     [1] panic buying
                     [2] Hurricane Harvey
                     [3] help from oil companies
    )
```

i don't know if i am making sense, any help would be really appreciated. i am really stuck on what i am doing right now.

Comment: Don't use `leftJoin`, try `eagar loading` which is a laravel's Eloquent method.  I recommend @Rinto George answer

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

In Laravel you can use [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent.).

When using Eloquent, you don't need to write your own query, eloquent will manage the relations.

Create a model and use `hasMany`

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Question extends Model
{
    

    public function choices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Choice', 'question_id');
    }

}
```

And in your choice model

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Choice extends Model
{
    

    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Question');
    }
}
```

And in your blade template it would be easy to fetch this record via this function in model

```
@foreach($questions as $question)

//will have $question and $question->choices

@endforeach
```

Comment: hello sir, i tried it, but the output is, it gets all the data in the choices table, but i just want to get the data in choices based on what id i have in my question table data.

Comment: Relations used to get the results like the later you said. If you use it correctly, in the foreach you will have question and it's choices, next iteration will have question and it's choices , and so on...

Comment: and in the controller, you can something like `Question::with('choices')->get();`

Comment: @ Rinto George 
please help me with this question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081641/add-div-tag-inside-all-li-with-matching-class-name-using-php/64092865#64092865

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend handling it using collections. So if we assume you already have an array of questions and an array of answers, a piece of code as below will meet your need. The point is that it would not need any query to the database and all processes will be handled on the application layer.

```
$questions = [...]; // array of questions
$answers = [...]; // array of answers 

$questionsCollection = new Collection($questions);
$answersCollection = new Collection($answers);

$groupedAnswers = $answersCollection->groupBy('question_id');
$questionAndAnswers = $groupedAnswers->map( function ($choices, $questionId) use ($questionsCollection) {
    $question = $questionsCollection->where('id', $questionId)->first();
    $question['choices'] = $choices;
    return $question;
});
```

**brief what am I doing in the code:**

- Im creating an instance of collections using desired arrays. So I can use the array's data while using Collection methods.
- all choices are grouped together based on question_id.
- using the "map" method and its callback enables us to iterate over answers and find their related question using the "where" method and the question_id available on each iteration.

[You can find more about collections here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby)